# How to call a function when a property is used?

Tags: javascript

When I change a property in a JavaScript "class" I want to log to the console when the old deprecated property is used.

eg.

```
var app = function() {
    this.oldvar = function() { console.log('oldvar is old!'); return myapp.newvar; };
    this.newvar = 'Hello world!';
}

var myapp = new app();

alert(myapp.oldvar);
```

My example will not work because the string representation of `oldvar` will be outputted and the function won't actually be called.

I want the `alert()` to think it's using the old property but "extra" code will be run in the function.

**I do not want to call oldvar as a function. I want my code to try and `alert()` it as a string.**

Is this possible?

Comment: I think the proposed solutions will not work, because it's implied that `myapp.oldvar` already exists in code. I think you should look at ES5 getters.

Comment: You are correct Arturo.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a `get`ter for your `app` like this:

```
var app = function () {
    this.newvar = 'Hello world!';
};

app.prototype = {
    get oldvar() {
        console.log('oldvar is old!');
        return this.newvar;
    }
};

var myapp = new app();

alert(myapp.oldvar);
```

I've tested this in Node.js v0.10.32 and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcudtsqm/1/) in the latest Chrome and it seems to work for me. However, this is a *relatively* recent feature in ECMA Script, so older browsers won't support it. I refer you to the [Mozilla Developer Network Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Browser_compatibility) for the compatibility table.

The above method involves redefining the `prototype` of your `app`. This is probably fine if `app` is entirely your own function. However, if you're using an existing function and don't want to override everything there already, you can use this alternative syntax:

```
var app = function () {
    this.newvar = 'Hello world!';
};

Object.defineProperty(app.prototype, 'oldvar', {
    get: function () {
        console.log('oldvar is old!');
        return this.newvar;
    }
});

var myapp = new app();

alert(myapp.oldvar);
```

Using this syntax, you can add new `get`ters without having to re-define all your old ones. If you then want to delete it, you can use the standard `delete` function in JavaScript, i.e. `delete app.prototype.oldvar;`.

Comment: @nbrooks sorry, you two are indeed right. I answered the question in a hurry before leaving for lunch. I've updated it now and hopefully this is now relevant.

Comment: @Jared does this meet your requirements or are there any other issues I'm not aware of?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have yet to test it and I'm giving the question some time if anyone else has a different answer.

Answer (score 2):

The suggested solutions will not work, because `oldvar` needs to be treated as a property, not as a function.

Try using getters, defined in ECMAScript 5 (so only newer browsers will support it, i.e. nothing before IE9)

Example:

```
var app = {
    newvar: 'Hello world!'
};

Object.defineProperty(app, 'oldvar', {
    get: function() {
        console.log('oldvar is old!');
        return this.newvar;
    }
});
```

You can read more about them here: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/12/es5-getters-setters/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the oldVar property as a function:
Use `alert(myapp.oldvar());`

Comment: I don't want to call `oldvar` as a function. I want to use it as a variable.